# php app/console assetic:dump produces unwanted files

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I've installed some components, such as foundation, jquery, etc, in my Symfony 2.8 application. I've also installed `assetic` in order to use these components, I thought, more easily.

I've the following configuration for `assetic` in my `config.yml` file:

```
...    

assetic:

    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"

    bundles:
        # Defaults (all currently registered bundles):
        - FrameworkBundle
        - SecurityBundle
        - TwigBundle
        - MonologBundle
        - SwiftmailerBundle
        - DoctrineBundle
        - SensioFrameworkExtraBundle
        - AsseticBundle

    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~

    assets:

        normalize_css:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../components/normalize-css/normalize.css
            filters: [cssrewrite]

        foundation_min_css:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../components/foundation/css/foundation.min.css
            filters: [cssrewrite]

        jquery:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../components/jquery/jquery.js

        foundation_min_js:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js
```

but when I type the following command on the console to generate statically the files under the `web` folder:

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

I obtain, I think, multiple versions of the same file but named differently:

[image]

Why is that happening and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Not sure, but I think the dev environnement, always dumps two version : the source version and a filtered version applying (or not) your filters. Don't know how to avoid it.